# Can C++ structs be casted to Microsoft Bond structs?

Tags: c++, struct, bond

The goal is to transform a C++ struct provided to a bond struct. Is this supported by Bond?

Otherwise are there any good examples available to generically transform a C++ struct to a compiled bond struct? I'd prefer to centralize this logic opposed to creating a custom transform for every bond struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can provide a specialization for [`bond::schema<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/8d0842280856f357664d6ea9d3d010497444e8ab/cpp/inc/bond/core/traits.h#L38-L46) for the non-Bond generated struct, that would give enough compile-time metadata about the non-Bond struct that many of the Bond APIs could be called on the non-Bond generated struct, like the [transforms](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#transforms) APIs. For example, [serialization of `std::tuple<T...>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/bd4b46e78a82dd3a38b52b00233a1a22047014d2/cpp/inc/bond/core/tuple.h) is implemented by specializing `bond::schema<std::tuple<T...>>`.

C++ does not--[yet](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3814.html)--have compile-time reflection for structs. There are various ways of simulating this (e.g., [Boost::Fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830792/simulate-compile-time-reflection-in-c), macro-based schemes, code generation tools). A large part of Bond's C++ code generation is adding [compile-time schema](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#compile-time-schema) that the library later uses.

If the C++ struct and the Bond-generated C++ struct have compatible layout and both are [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable), you can use `std::memcpy` to "cast-by-copying" to the Bond-generated struct and then manipulate the Bond struct as needed. I'd wrap such behavior in a helper method with generous `static_assert` checks to avoid undefined behavior as the structs evolve. This will only work on very constrained struct shapes: collection fields, for example, will likely render the struct non-trivially copyable. You need to be using the 8.x or later version Bond and a recent version of your C++ compiler for the generated Bond structs to even have the ability to be trivially copyable at all. (See commit [fa02289f](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/commit/fa02289f1146724cdbc6d4ec6a0c506b1214ef4c) which removed many non-default ctors.)